# Set Theory. Arbitrary, denumerable and Cross Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble understanding this - especially the arbitrary part.

> $X$ is an arbitrary set, $M\subseteq X$ is an arbitrary denumerable set, $M'\subseteq X$ is an arbitrary finite set.

1) Is $M\times M$ denumerable?

2) Is $M'\times M'$ denumerable?

What does arbitrary mean in this context? I am having trouble understanding the difference between $M$ and $M'$. I do not know how to work with an "arbitrary set". What is that?!

Comment: "Arbitrary" has no formal effect. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308516/terminology-arbitrary-vs-finite/308562#308562).

Comment: $M$ and $M'$ are just two sets - denumerable and finite, respectively. "Arbitrary" just means that we let them be any such sets, i.e., we don't assume that $M\supseteq M'$ for example.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks. That helped. So both sets must be denumberable?

Comment: @Chrissl: It says explicitly that $M'$ must be _finite_. Usually "denumerable" means "countably infinite", so $M'$ cannot be denumerable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm But why are infite sets denumerable and finite sets not?! If something is denumerable in infinity, something finite should be denumerable too?!

Comment: @Chrissl: Not all infinite sets are denumerable. At this point you really should look in your textbook for its _exact_ definition of the word "denumerable".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Of course not all infinite sets are denumerable. I am aware of that! What I cannot grasp is why something infinte is not denumerable.

Comment: @Chrissl: I don't see any difference between what you claim you are "of course" aware of, and the thing you "cannot grasp". Which difference is there between them?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I understand that infinite(!) sets can be either denumerable or nondenumerable. What I do not understand is, why M' is nondenumerable. That is a finite set. If something is finite, I should be able to denumerable it?!

Comment: @Chrissl: Again, you need to tell us the exact definition of the word "denumerable" you're working with here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Like in Cantor.

Comment: @Chrissl: "Like in Cantor" is not a definition of the word "denumerable". If you refuse to reveal the _actual definition_ you're working with, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @Chrissl Some people use "denumerable" to mean "countable *and infinite*," others just use it to mean "countable (possibly finite)". So you need to clarify.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I meant with "like in Cantor" the way he uses denumerable when he proves that |N| = |Q+| or that one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument. Basically, denumerable means (for me) bijection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection.

Comment: @Chrissl: That is still not an actual definition of the word "denumerable". If you want help, provide an actual verbatim quote of the definition in the textbook you're using. (And nobody uses the word "denumerable" as a synonym of "bijection").

Comment: @HenningMakholm A set is denumerable if there a bijection.

Comment: @Chrissl: You're missing several words there. You seem to be deliberately difficult here, repeatedly refusing to quote the definition you're using. I conclude you're just a troll, not really interested in being helped, and I have better things to do than keep trying to get you to reveal the definitions you're ostensibly asking for help with understanding. Goodbye!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for sticking with me :) Have a good one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product of two finite sets is finite and the product of two denumerable sets is denumerable. This is pretty easy to prove. To prove the latter statement you need to find a bijection from the set of positive integers onto the set of ordered pairs of positive integers. To do this all you need to do is find a way of putting all the ordered pairs of positive integers into an infinite sequence indexed by the positive integers. If you write them up in an infinite two-dimensional array then you can actually draw a picture of how it works. Have a think about it.

Comment: I do know how to prove it. But I do not know how to work with an "arbitrary set". What is that?!

Comment: @Chrissl: Have you followed the link I keep giving you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yep. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308516/terminology-arbitrary-vs-finite/308562#308562 But I did not understand your answere :)

Comment: "Arbitrary subset" just means "any possible subset".  So the Reader is asked to reason about a general subset (using only the assumed finiteness or denumerability), and not to provide an argument that works only for a particular subset.